# How to control the whitespace below wrapfigure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, layout

I'm currently working on a term paper on neural networks that I'm writing in LateX.

I have an itemize environment (with different activation functions) and want to display the graphs of the functions next to them. To do so I created a coordinate system with tikz and pgfplots.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\section{Aktivierungsfunktionen}

Neben den Gewichten und dem Bias ist der Output eines Neurons abhängig von seiner Aktivierungsfunktion $\varphi$. Diese dient dazu, den Output des Neurons nicht-linear zu machen. Würde ein neuronales Netz nur lineare Aktivierungsfunktionen nutzen, würde der Nutzen der verschiedenen Layer verloren gehen, da jede Komposition linearer Funktionen als Linearkombination der anderen Funktionen dargestellt werden kann. So hätte man effektiv nur ein Layer, da der Output des Netzes linear abhängig vom Input wäre. Welche Aktivierungsfunktionen in einem Netz verwendet werden, ist abhängig von dem Problem, das es lösen soll.\\

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=8cm, height=8cm, axis lines=center, xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}, xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, grid=both, minor tick num=1, legend pos=south east]

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, darkyellow] {x};
    \addlegendentry{Identity}

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, red] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
    \addlegendentry{Sigmoid}

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, cyan] {(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(exp(x) + exp(-x))};
    \addlegendentry{TanH}

    \addplot[domain=-3:0, samples=500, line width=1, blue] {0};
    \addplot[domain=0:3, samples=500, line width=1, dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt, blue] {x};
    \addlegendentry{ReLU}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent Die bekanntesten Aktivierungsfunktionen sind:

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Identity:} Die Identity-Funktion besitzt die Form $f(x)=x$. Allerdings wird sie aus oben genannten Gründen nur in sehr einfachen Modellen verwendet, da die Funktion linear ist.
    \item \textbf{Sigmoid:} Die Sigmoid-Funktion wird sehr häufig als Aktivierungsfunktion genutzt. Ihre Output-Werte liegen im Intervall $[0, 1]$. Sie ist definiert als\\ $f(x)=\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$.
    \item \textbf{TanH (Tangens Hyperbolicus):} Die TanH-Funktion hat wie die Sigmoid-Funktion einen S-förmigen Graphen. Allerdings liegen ihre Output-Werte im Intervall $[-1, 1]$. Ihre Funktionsgleichung ist $f(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$.
    \item \textbf{Rectifier (ReLU):} Die ReLU-Funktion ist ebenfalls eine sehr häufig genutzte Aktivierungsfunktion. Sie ist im Grunde zweigeteilt: Für $x<=0$ ist sie definiert als $f(x)=0$ und für $x>0$ als $f(x)=x$. Daher liegen ihre Werte im Intervall $[0, \infty)$. Ihre Funktionsgleichung kann auch als $f(x)=max(0, x)$ dargestellt werden. 
    \item \textbf{Softmax:} Eine Ausnahme stellt die Softmax-Funktion dar. Im Gegensatz zu den anderen genannten Funktionen nimmt sie nicht nur einen Wert als Input, sondern einen Input-Vektor $\Vec{x}$ mit allen Netzinputs eines gesamten Layers. Alle Werte des Output-Vektors $\Vec{o}$ liegen im Intervall $[0, 1]$, wobei sie sich alle zu 1 aufsummieren. Daher kann der Output genutzt werden, um eine Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilung darzustellen. Aus diesem Grund findet die Softmax-Funktion häufig Verwendung im Output-Layer eines Klassifizierungs-Netzes.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I cant manage to fit the tikzpicture next to the itemize. I tried using wrapfigure, which is kinda working...

Currently it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4roXs.jpg
But I want the text to continue below the tikzpicture (also the softmax item), like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jtcr.jpg

**Edit:** Code is now compilable.

Comment: Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official Stack Exchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: Ctrl+G). This ensures that all images will always be accessible and won't expire.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dexteritas I tried uploading the pictures directly, but this didn't work, I don't know why. So I decided to post the imgur links directly. I edited the code, it should be compilable now. Thank you!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I already tried using the [lineheight] argument, however it produces the following error: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Comment: It is very cumbersome to give you more feedback since you only post code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the number that are to be jumped over and split the `itemize` environment. Please note that `\\` should not be used to start a new line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\hyphenation{ge-nutzt}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Aktivierungsfunktionen}
\label{sec:Aktivierungsfunktionen}

Neben den Gewichten und dem Bias ist der Output eines Neurons abh\"angig von
seiner Aktivierungsfunktion $\varphi$. Diese dient dazu, den Output des Neurons
nicht-linear zu machen. W\"urde ein neuronales Netz nur lineare
Aktivierungsfunktionen nutzen, w\"urde der Nutzen der verschiedenen Layer verloren
gehen, da jede Komposition linearer Funktionen als Linearkombination der anderen
Funktionen dargestellt werden kann. So h\"atte man effektiv nur ein Layer, da der
Output des Netzes linear abh\"angig vom Input w\"are. Welche Aktivierungsfunktionen
in einem Netz verwendet werden, ist abh\"angig von dem Problem, das es l\"osen
soll.

\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}[10pt]{7.6cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=8cm, height=8cm, axis lines=center, xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}, xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, grid=both, minor tick num=1, legend pos=south east]

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, yellow!60!black] {x};
    \addlegendentry{Identity}

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, red] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
    \addlegendentry{Sigmoid}

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, cyan] {(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(exp(x) + exp(-x))};
    \addlegendentry{TanH}

    \addplot[domain=-3:0, samples=500, line width=1, blue] {0};
    \addplot[domain=0:3, samples=500, line width=1, dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt, blue] {x};
    \addlegendentry{ReLU}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}


\noindent Die bekanntesten Aktivierungsfunktionen sind:


\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Identity:} Die Identity-Funktion besitzt die Form $f(x)=x$.
Allerdings wird sie aus oben genannten Gr\"unden nur in sehr einfachen Modellen
verwendet, da die Funktion linear ist.
    \item \textbf{Sigmoid:} Die Sigmoid-Funktion wird sehr h\"aufig als
Aktivierungsfunktion genutzt. Ihre Output-Werte liegen im Intervall $[0, 1]$.
Sie ist definiert als $f(x)=\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{TanH (Tangens Hyperbolicus):} Die TanH-Funktion hat wie die
Sigmoid-Funktion einen S-f\"ormigen Graphen. Allerdings liegen ihre Output-Werte
im Intervall $[-1, 1]$. Ihre Funktionsgleichung ist
$f(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$.
    \item \textbf{Rectifier (ReLU):} Die ReLU-Funktion ist ebenfalls eine sehr
h\"aufig genutzte Aktivierungsfunktion. Sie ist im Grunde zweigeteilt: F\"ur $x<=0$
ist sie definiert als $f(x)=0$ und f\"ur $x>0$ als $f(x)=x$. Daher liegen ihre
Werte im Intervall $[0, \infty)$. Ihre Funktionsgleichung kann auch als
$f(x)=max(0, x)$ dargestellt werden. 
    \item \textbf{Softmax:} Eine Ausnahme stellt die Softmax-Funktion dar. Im
Gegensatz zu den anderen genannten Funktionen nimmt sie nicht nur einen Wert als
Input, sondern einen Input-Vektor $\vec{x}$ mit allen Netzinputs eines gesamten
Layers. Alle Werte des Output-Vektors $\vec{o}$ liegen im Intervall $[0, 1]$,
wobei sie sich alle zu 1 aufsummieren. Daher kann der Output genutzt werden, um
eine Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilung darzustellen. Aus diesem Grund findet die
Softmax-Funktion h\"aufig Verwendung im Output-Layer eines
Klassifizierungs-Netzes.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\hyphenation{ge-nutzt}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Aktivierungsfunktionen}
\label{sec:Aktivierungsfunktionen}

Neben den Gewichten und dem Bias ist der Output eines Neurons abh\"angig von
seiner Aktivierungsfunktion $\varphi$. Diese dient dazu, den Output des Neurons
nicht-linear zu machen. W\"urde ein neuronales Netz nur lineare
Aktivierungsfunktionen nutzen, w\"urde der Nutzen der verschiedenen Layer verloren
gehen, da jede Komposition linearer Funktionen als Linearkombination der anderen
Funktionen dargestellt werden kann. So h\"atte man effektiv nur ein Layer, da der
Output des Netzes linear abh\"angig vom Input w\"are. Welche Aktivierungsfunktionen
in einem Netz verwendet werden, ist abh\"angig von dem Problem, das es l\"osen
soll.


Die bekanntesten Aktivierungsfunktionen sind:

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{r}[10pt]{7.6cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=8cm, height=8cm, axis lines=center, xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}, xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, grid=both, minor tick num=1, legend pos=south east]

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, yellow!60!black] {x};
    \addlegendentry{Identity}

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, red] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
    \addlegendentry{Sigmoid}

    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=500, line width=1, cyan] {(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(exp(x) + exp(-x))};
    \addlegendentry{TanH}

    \addplot[domain=-3:0, samples=500, line width=1, blue] {0};
    \addplot[domain=0:3, samples=500, line width=1, dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt, blue] {x};
    \addlegendentry{ReLU}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
~\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Identity:} Die Identity-Funktion besitzt die Form $f(x)=x$.
Allerdings wird sie aus oben genannten Gr\"unden nur in sehr einfachen Modellen
verwendet, da die Funktion linear ist.
    \item \textbf{Sigmoid:} Die Sigmoid-Funktion wird sehr h\"aufig als
Aktivierungsfunktion genutzt. Ihre Output-Werte liegen im Intervall $[0, 1]$.
Sie ist definiert als $f(x)=\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{TanH (Tangens Hyperbolicus):} Die TanH-Funktion hat wie die
Sigmoid-Funktion einen S-f\"ormigen Graphen. Allerdings liegen ihre Output-Werte
im Intervall $[-1, 1]$. Ihre Funktionsgleichung ist
$f(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$.
    \item \textbf{Rectifier (ReLU):} Die ReLU-Funktion ist ebenfalls eine sehr
h\"aufig genutzte Aktivierungsfunktion. Sie ist im Grunde zweigeteilt: F\"ur $x<=0$
ist sie definiert als $f(x)=0$ und f\"ur $x>0$ als $f(x)=x$. Daher liegen ihre
Werte im Intervall $[0, \infty)$. Ihre Funktionsgleichung kann auch als
$f(x)=max(0, x)$ dargestellt werden. 
    \item \textbf{Softmax:} Eine Ausnahme stellt die Softmax-Funktion dar. Im
Gegensatz zu den anderen genannten Funktionen nimmt sie nicht nur einen Wert als
Input, sondern einen Input-Vektor $\vec{x}$ mit allen Netzinputs eines gesamten
Layers. Alle Werte des Output-Vektors $\vec{o}$ liegen im Intervall $[0, 1]$,
wobei sie sich alle zu 1 aufsummieren. Daher kann der Output genutzt werden, um
eine Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilung darzustellen. Aus diesem Grund findet die
Softmax-Funktion h\"aufig Verwendung im Output-Layer eines
Klassifizierungs-Netzes.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to move the picture downwards, so that the sentence "Die bekanntesten Aktivierungsfunktionen..." is not splitted?

Comment: @Jannik Yes, of course. I added a code for that.

Comment: Thanks, I had to adjust the values a little bit but it's working now!